# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ...is not clickable at point (x, y)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I am trying to use Selenium to click on the search box. 
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/mypath/chromedriver",
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)

thing_url = "https://www.target.com/"
driver.get(thing_url)
time.sleep(10)
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
element_position = searchbox.location["y"]
driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, {})".format(element_position))
time.sleep(10)
searchbox.click()
```

I did a lot of Google search and applied the suggestion such as making the chrome browser full page before the click, or adding a delay before the click etc but none is working.

Here is the full error message that I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input id="search" name="searchTerm" class="form--control js-searchTerm" type="search" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="searchLabel"> is not clickable at point (955, 20). Other element would receive the click: <label id="searchLabel" for="search" data-text="search" aria-hidden="true">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

I am using Python 3.6 on a Mac.
After the WebDriver opens Chrome I see a page like this:

[image]

Please see the black bar on top of the search bar, but after a few seconds the black bar disappears and looks like search bar location moves. Please see below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


search_box = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "search")))
search_box.send_keys("Test.")

search_button = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#searchReset[data-search='submit']")))
search_button.click())
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you. Where in the code shall I add it and what does it do?

Comment: I added right before searchbox.click() and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @TJ1, you should add after `searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("search")` line.

Comment: I still get the same error! can you please try the code yourself?

Comment: @TJ1, I have updated my answer. Try on. It must work.

Comment: I get `Unresolved Reference` error for `WebDriverWait`, for `EC` and for `By`, what are these?

Comment: I still get the same error.  have noticed a change in the location of searchbox,   will update my question with some screen shots. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162292/discussion-between-ratmir-asanov-and-tj1).

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be. You are trying to scroll when the search box is at the top of the page. You are also trying to click the `INPUT` when all you need to do is `.send_keys()`.

```
thing_url = "https://www.target.com/"
driver.get(thing_url) # no need for a sleep after this
driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys("shorts")
```

I'm assuming you don't work for Target and so you don't need to test the UI. The easier way to do this is to just use the search URL, e.g.

https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=shorts

https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=mens+shorts

Comment: Thanks. I get this error when I run your code:
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x1022843c8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

Comment: You've made an error elsewhere. There's nothing in my code above that should cause any kind of errors. It's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I don't use python but I wrote this in Java and converted it. Simple code like this should work without issues.